# Clarification on 师 meaning

Tags: difference

I am trying to learn some vocabulary thanks to memrise.com.

In the word list, 师 is mentionned two times, once meaning "teacher"(pinyin: shi1), the second one as an adjective meaning "handsome, smart" (pinyin shuai4).

I can't find the second meaning anywhere else online. Is this an error from the site, or something deprecated or unusual ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar characters:
师 shi1

帅 shuai4

I would imagine someone mixed them up accidentally.

Comment: My bad, the site is actually correct, but I had not noticed the difference. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 5):

It is good to make a distinction here,

First they both have a 巾 radical, which means scarf,

师 means a teacher with a stroke (hat) over the scarf (巾),

帅 means a leader (particularly a general in the battle field) when a teacher is taking off the hat and go on the battle field. Also, as an adjective it means handsome because a general in the battle field looks handsome (not necessarily appearance) because he or she must be brave and charismatic in the field.

Comment: Very interesting, and a good way to remember how to make the distinction between the two.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they are the same. My guess is one is 師 and the other is 帥.